# What is the meaning of `$this->{$this}` in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have encountered that in `Authenticatable` trait  in laravel:

```php
 public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value; //here
        }
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }
```

I know the first `$this` will point out the class (Model) that the trait is used in. However,

- What is the meaning of the second `{$this}`?
- What does it actually do?
- Why they did not simply say:

```php
 public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->rememberTokenName = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Laravel doesn't know what `rememberTokenField` your model will use. you might all it `remember_token` or something else. Therefore it uses that code in that way to allow you to override `getRememberTokenName` or simply change the value of `rememberTokenName` and use your own field without needing to override `setRememberToken`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trait is using the value returned from `getRememberTokenName()`, which is really just the value of `$this->rememberTokenName`, as the name of the property in the model class that should hold the value. For instance, if `$this->rememberTokenName` is set to 'myToken', the `setRememberTokenFunction` is doing the equivalent of

```php
$this->myToken = $value;
```

This is just a convoluted way of allowing the model class to configure the name of the variable that holds the token value.

```php
<?php

trait Authenticatable
{
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // If there is a token name...
        if (!empty($this->getRememberTokenName()))
        {
            /*
             * Set the property with the token name to the provided value
             * Example: if $this->getRememberTokenName() returns 'myToken',
             * this is equivalent to $this->myToken = $value 
             */
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }
}

class Model
{
    use Authenticatable;

    private $myToken;
    private $rememberTokenName = 'myToken';

    public function __construct($myToken)
    {
        $this->myToken = $myToken;
    }

    public function getMyToken()
    {
        return $this->myToken;
    }
}

$myModel = new Model('foo');

assert($myModel->getMyToken() == 'foo', 'Token should match constructor argument');

$myModel->setRememberToken('bar');

$updatedToken = $myModel->getMyToken();

assert($updatedToken == 'bar', 'Token should have been updated by trait');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is [complex curly syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).
Basically if `$this->getRememberTokenName()` returns the string value `six` then the expression is essentially      `$this->six`